# java Complex Regex doesn't work in String.matches()

Tags: java, regex, match

i have this regex which i want to check if string do contain this structure 
none of the strings below match , why?

```
String s = "T4018.test.12"
or 
String s = "T4018.foo.32"
or 
String s = "develop"



if(s.matches("T40[0-9][0-9][.][a-zA-Z]+|develop"))
{
    //Never matches 
}
```

its do match :
https://regex101.com/r/CSLugb/1
**UPDATE**
Solved it using Pattern.compile

Comment: `[0-9][0-9]` only matches two digits correct? All your `String`'s contain four or none

Comment: It must match `develop`. `matches` requires a full string match and `T40[0-9][0-9][.][a-zA-Z]+` cannot match the last `.` and digits in your first two strings

Comment: The [a-z]+ part won't match what comes after: `.12` for example isn't letters.

Comment: when i test it in https://regex101.com/ 
i do see it matches the string's 
https://regex101.com/r/CSLugb/1

Comment: Your link even proves why it won't match, or have you missed what ".12" isn't matched in your link?

Comment: It seems to match, see [test](https://regex101.com/r/754kRy/1)

Comment: @GBlodgett The first two digits are part of the "T40". Only the last two digits  (of the four-digit number) need to match with `[0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: Also works for me in Java: it **does** match the string "develop";  Check your test harness.

Comment: Works: `public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String regex = "T40[0-9][0-9][.][a-zA-Z]+|develop";
      String s = "develop";
      System.out.println( s.matches( regex ) );
   }`

Comment: But in Java the whole string is used for matching and your RegEx does not cover the last dot and following number (’.12’ or ’.32’). See this [test of your RegEx](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyw9ydar)

Comment: it do match "develop" but not the other string , i need 1 regex that match all options

Comment: Well see the answers above for why.  I think it's obvious that the ".12" part of your string needs to be included in the regex you gave, and it just isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can rewrite the RegEx to `"T40\\d{2}\\.\\w+\\.\\d{2}|develop"` for matching more exactly. See your 3 test-cases [matched in Java](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyy4pu2tnr)

Comment: do not match : T4018.foo.32.b

Comment: This test-case `T4018.foo.32.b` was not specified in your question. The RegEx `"T40\\d{2}\\.\\w+\\.\\d{2}(\\.\\w+)?|develop"` will also match it because _group_  of <dot plus one ore multiple word-characters> could also exist either once or never `(\\.\\w+)?`